# How to use .NET to Turn the Monitor back on after the Idle Timer has Turned it Off?

Tags: c#, windows-7, monitor, power-management, wakeup

How do I turn the monitor back on after the idle timer has turned it off?
I have power options in windows 7 set to:
Turn off monitor after: 1 minute
Go to sleep: Never

But I don't know how to turn it back on through code.

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Monitor_management_guide.aspx

It uses the"SendMessage" API call:

> SC_MONITORPOWER Sets the state of the
>   display. This command supports devices
>   that have power-saving features, such
>   as a battery-powered personal
>   computer. The lParam parameter can
>   have the following values:
>
> -1 - the display is powering on
>
> 1 - the display is going to low power
>
> 2 - the display is being shut off

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to turn it on, or just prevent it from turning off?  If the latter, you can use the WinAPI:

SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED)

I don't think that there is a .net wrapper built in, but you should be able to pInvoke it.